# A relationship between the values of an invariant vector field at the identity and another element

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $G(R^n)$ be the general linear group, and $g(R^n)$ the set of all linear transformations on $R^n$, and $\mathscr g$ the Lie algebra of $G(R^n)$. We define a function $J:\mathscr g \to g(R^n)$ by $<J(X)v,w>=X(e)f_{v,w}$, where $X\in \mathscr g$ and $e$ is the identity in $G(R^n)$ and $v,w\in \mathbb R^n$ and $f_{v,w}:G(R^n)\to \mathbb R$ is given by $T\mapsto <Tv,w>$.

My problem is I strongly believe that $<AJ(X)v,w>=X(A)f_{v,w}$ for all $A\in G(R^n)$ but I couldn’t prove it even using the fact that $X$ is invariant. How should I show that?

If I show that, in fact I will have established an isomorphism between the two Lie algebras above. By the way I know a more natural isomorphism between them so my question is not really about isomorphism.

Comment: It confuses me that you're doing all this with inner products. So you're thinking of $\mathscr g$ as the vector space of left-invariant vector fields on $G$ (which we can canonically identify with the tangent space at the identity). You're trying to avoid the exponential map?

Comment: @TedShifrin this method is suggested by my book but it doesn’t show why this method establishes an isomorphism. Exponential map has not been defined in the book so far although I’m close to reading it.

Comment: I don't know much about differential geometry, so it's possible that what I'm saying is nonsense, but are you somehow defining the adjoint map of GL(n) or something like that?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be $v,w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Considering the natural bases $e_i$ we can form a well-defined function using the inner product. So it’s not about adjoint. I’ll edit the typo you mentioned. Thanks @stressedout

Comment: Like Ted Shifrin implies, using the inner product isn't necessary, and it creates unnecessary confusion. If $\tilde X \in \Gamma(T(G(R^2)))$ is the left-invariant vector field characterized by $\tilde X_e = X$, by definition for any $A \in G(R^2)$ we have $\tilde X_A = T_e L_A (\tilde X_e)$, where $L_A$ is the map on $G(R^2)$ given by multiplication by $A$ on the left. But $L_A$ is the restriction of a linear map, so under the usual canonical isomorphisms we can identify $T_e L_A \leftrightarrow L_A$ and so $T_e L_A(X) \leftrightarrow A X$.

Comment: @Travis Thanks, I think the only point as you mentioned that I missed was the linearity of $L_g$.

Comment: As to Ted Shifrin and Travis saying that the use of inner product is unnecessary, I have seen such a method of defining functions in differential geometry, for example in the context of curvature.